# I want to make incremental backups of the entire system to a SMB share. Help

Tags: backup, samba

I want to back up my server to an Apple Time Capsule using `rdiff-backup`. However the SMB/CIFS protocol it uses (do not talk about AFP, it won't work under wily despite supporting most features Linux would like to see) get choked when symlinks are involved.

How to do that then, without pre-allocating lots of space for a disk image?